# python time now and before

Tags: python, time

how i can do the checking. so that if the time which i write in the h m s format hasnt yet come, add yesterdays date to it

for example:
now 00:10:15 ,    i input 00:15:15    bot write 2022-09-09 00:15:15

and if the time has come to add todays

for example:
now 00:10:15 , i input 00:10:00  , bot write 2022-09-10  00:10:00

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import pytz

#date = datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Pacific/Kwajalein"))

newYorkTz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Kiev") 
timeInNewYork = datetime.now(newYorkTz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d ')
#date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d ')
from_date = str(input('time): '))


fulldate = timeInNewYork + from_date

dt = datetime.strptime(fulldate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
epoch = dt.timestamp() 

print(epoch)
```

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear. Can you explain the problem with your code and the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `if.. else` statement to check if the input time has passed (compared to the actual time) or not. If so, you can use [**`timedelta`**](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html) to add one day and get your timestamp.

Try this :

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import time
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import pytz

#date = datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Pacific/Kwajalein"))

newYorkTz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Kiev") 
timeInNewYork = datetime.now(newYorkTz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d ')

now = datetime.now(newYorkTz)

from_date = str(input('time): '))
my_datetime = datetime.strptime(from_date, "%H:%M:%S")
my_datetime = now.replace(hour=my_datetime.time().hour, minute=my_datetime.time().minute, second=my_datetime.time().second, microsecond=0)

fulldate = timeInNewYork + ' ' + from_date

if (now > my_datetime):
    dt = datetime.strptime(fulldate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    epoch = dt.timestamp() 
else:
    dt = datetime.strptime(fulldate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(days=-1)
    epoch = dt.timestamp() 

print(dt)
print(epoch)
```

##### `>>> Test with a past time`

```
time):  11:55:33
2022-09-10 11:55:33
1662803733.0
```

##### `>>> Test with a future time`

```
time):  19:00:33
2022-09-09 19:00:33
1662915633.0
```

Comment: @lartiste
hi, if past time of day today (+3) need write write time+day today
` for example now 18:40 , i input 16:40
write 10-09-2022 16:40`

and if hasnt yet come, add yesterdays date to it

`now 18:40, i input 19:40

write 09-09-2022 19:40  (day before)`

Comment: In this case, we need `timedelta(days=-1)`. I updated my answer. Check it out!

Comment: @lartiste
its work, thx!
but now the problem will write the future tense, but that's another story)

Comment: I'm afraid to not understand. Can you give an example, please ?

Comment: you also need to write down the future tense, for example, add + to the time when you enter
e.g. 13:31:30+

Comment: You're welcome. Have you managed to write what you're looking for ? Because I still can't understand the issue with the future tense. Maybe you can give an example.